# Make process window visible/Invisble in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, resize, visible

I have my application, in which I am starting a new process. But I need to resize the window in the process to fit into my requirement. But first the process opens the window in normal size and then I resize it to fit. This make it look odd. So can I start the process with the winodw in invisible mode and then resize and then make it visible?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myApp.exe");
MyApp = Process.Start(startInfo);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
MoveWindow(MyApp.MainWindowHandle, 0, 380, 2040, 1150, true);
```

Comment: Are you talking about a Windows form or a windows service ?  You say service however services generally do not contain UI.

Comment: perhaps it would be even better to make myApp.exe take some commandline arguments and resize itself - no waiting, no odd looking

Comment: On a side note `Thread.Sleep(2000)` makes me cringe.  Is there a way you can test if the window is loaded and loop until that happens?

Comment: @Robotsushi: I said process. It is just an exe just like say IE or notepad

Comment: @Yahia: Not possible. As i don't have the source code for the exe

Comment: @Hand-E-Food: The sleep is coz it takes time for the Window to load. I tried without it and it didn't work.

Comment: I understand that, but how can you guarantee that the program will load within 2 seconds?  Regardless, that's a separate issue and I'm off topic.

Answer (score 4):

Tried `startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` before .Start() call to hide it? And then use your code to show it?

Like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myApp.exe");

startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

MyApp = Process.Start(startInfo);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
MoveWindow(MyApp.MainWindowHandle, 0, 380, 2040, 1150, true);
```

To show the window import this method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
```

Then call it after MoveWindow function:

```
ShowWindow(MyApp.MainWindowHandle, 5);
```

Comment: This sounds a logical solution. But the system is throwing an exception in ShowWindow. Not able to figure out why.

Comment: What is the exception? Try this `ShowWindow(MyApp.MainWindowHandle, 1);` This should work for the windows that are shown for the first time... Heres the rest of the nCmdShow values, try some: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The crash was because of the wrong DLL. I have fixed that but still it is not working. The window doesn't show even after the ShowWindow.

Comment: And you did put 1 instead of 5?

Comment: Yes I tried that. I don't know if it has anything to do with ProcessStartInfo, the msn site says somethings about startupinfo, but I couldn't understand this.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx you should use `ShowWindowAsync` for Windows you don't own to avoid erratic results

Comment: Hey yeah, try ShowWindowAsync: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633549(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yahia, you must write the answer below. It was luck I look here.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx you should use ShowWindowAsync for Windows you don't own to avoid erratic results.

Answer (score 0):

considering that you are using a panel where your process is loading..
you can use this line of code

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
 Process p = new process(); // you can also use System.Diagnostics.Process
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
 info.FileName = // your Process
 info.Arguments = "Your Argument";
 info.UseShellExecute = true;
 info.CreateNoWindow = true;
 info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized; //this will make no effect, so optional
 info.RedirectStandardInput = false;
 info.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
 info.RedirectStandardError = false;
 p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
 p.WaitForInputIdle();
 Thread.Sleep(10000);
 SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.pnlAlpha.Handle);
 // You also need to use this line so that your window should be re-sized 
 MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, yourPanel.Width, yourPanel.Height, true);


//Dont forget to add this globally 
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("USER32.dll")]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
```